# How can I invoke this onkeydown event with a WebBrowserControl in C#?

Tags: c#, browser, webbrowser-control, dom

```
<input onkeydown="if(isNumber(event)) { this.value = isNumber(event); ajax_submit(this.form); bump_recruiter(); el('altsubmit').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled'); return false; }" class="captcha" type="text" id="number" name="number" value="">
```

That is the html. I tried this within the webBrowser.Navigate method:

javascript: ajax_submit(document.forms[0]); bump_recruiter(); el('altsubmit').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

The images didn't refresh and were all broken after executing that. I read on SO a bit and put this together:

```
HtmlElement answerField = _wBrowser.Document.GetElementById("number");
answerField.InnerText = answerString;
answerField.InvokeMember("onKeyDown()");
```

This didn't work either though and I've ran out of ideas. I'm reading up on general webbrowser control documentation, but not sure where or what to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this line is incorrect:

```
answerField.InvokeMember("onKeyDown()");
```

It should be:

```
answerField.InvokeMember("onKeyDown");
```

Comment: I had instances when this wouldn't reliably work, causing me to include mshtml and use the `IHTMLElement3` method `FireEvent()`.

Comment: Reflecting on this question, the above is an example of why "stringly typing" things is bad. Had I actually used a property or method (can't remember which) the compiler could have told me about this mistake.